# What are the limitations and challenges we have to face migrating from a VS lower version to higher version

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am to migrate my asp.net, c# application from a lower version to higher version VS2012 I want to know what are the limitations and challenges we have to face.

Comment: It is a real question that i dont find suitable soultion yet..

Answer (score 2):

Check out MSDN for compatibility and upgrading to VS2012  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx they know better than most of us here would.  I would say that going from 2010 to 2012 has so far been pretty easy for us, with the exception of database projects there really hasn't been much conversion.